# How can i do this ORACLE query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables : **Table 1** and **Table2** :

**Table1** have 2 columns

**Table2** have 3 columns

**Id** Column is common for **Table1** and **Table2**

**Table1** have  more **Id** than **Table2**

But i wish to have a query that returns me all the **Id** of the **Table1** with the Column 3 of the **Table2**

## Table1

```
+------+-------+
| Id   | Col2  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | 20000 |
|    2 | 20001 |
|    3 | 20002 |
|    4 | 20003 |
+------+-------+
```

## Table2

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Id   | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  100 |    1 |   25 |
|  100 |    2 |   50 |
|  100 |    4 |   40 |
+------+------+------+
```

I wish to have this table :

## Table3

```
+------+-------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2  |  Col3  |
+------+-------+------+-+
|    1 | 20000 |     25 |
|    2 | 20001 |     50 |
|    3 | 20002 |      0 |
|    4 | 20003 |     40 |
+------+-------+------+-+
```

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` + `COALESCE`

Comment: You are looking for an outer join, as already mentioned. But there is more to consider. Can an ID appear more than once in table2? It is likely to be the case, because otherwise, why have a separate table rather than simply having table1 hold more columns. But then: Do you want one result row per table1/2 match? Or one result row per ID? For the latter you would need aggregation (i.e. `GROUP BY id`) along with the decision what values of table2 to show in case of multiple matches (sums, maximums, whatever).

Comment: no in table2 i can't have a duplicated id, table1 have a static number of rows and table2 are rows inserted by the user based on the Id , so table2 have maximum number of rows  = number of rows of table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddb77b/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( Id, Col2 ) AS
          SELECT 1, 20000 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20001 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 20002 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 20003 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( Col1, Id, Col3 ) AS
          SELECT 100, 1, 25 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100, 2, 50 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100, 4, 40 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.Id,
       Col2,
       COALESCE( Col1, 100 ) AS Col1,
       COALESCE( Col3, 0 ) AS Col3
FROM   Table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Table2 t2
       ON ( t1.Id = t2.Id )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddb77b/4/0)**:

```
| ID |  COL2 | COL1 | COL3 |
|----|-------|------|------|
|  1 | 20000 |  100 |   25 |
|  2 | 20001 |  100 |   50 |
|  4 | 20003 |  100 |   40 |
|  3 | 20002 |  100 |    0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this "But i wish to have a query that returns me all the Id of the Table1 with the Column 3 of the Table2":

```
select t1.id, t2.Col3 from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

If you want to get Table 3:

```
select t1.id as Col1, t1.Col2, COALESCE(t2.Col1, 100) as Col3, COALESCE(t2.Col3, 0) as Col4 
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Don't forget to take care of NULL's.